# How can I make the changing without lose the knowledges in inheritance class?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

When I added the function to the `inheritance class` I don't want to lose the datas in `manager1` like `John Wood` `3000`, but when I added `raise_wage` function to `manager(worker)`, I equalled `manager2` to `manager("John Wood",3000,"IT")`, when I made this, I didn't use `manager1` and I lost `manager1` changings. For example I wrote `("John Wood",3000,"IT")` knowledges again at the end of the code and I lost departmand knowledges like `marketing`. How can I add the function like `raise_wage` and I don't lose the data like `marketing`?
At the end of the code `#manager2` parts are the codes that I don't want to write, but to add the `raise_wage` I had to add `#manager2` parts. I don't want to create `manager2` I want to protect `manager1` knowledges and add the function. How can I make this?

```
class worker():
    def __init__(self,name,wage,department):
        self.name=name
        self.wage=wage
        self.department=department
    def showtheknowledges(self):
        print("""name={}\nwage={}\ndepartment={}""".format(self.name,self.wage,self.department))
    def changethedepartment(self,new_department):
        self.department=new_department

class manager(worker):
    pass

manager1=manager("John Wood",3000,"IT")

manager1.showtheknowledges()

manager1.changethedepartment("marketing")

manager1.showtheknowledges()

class manager(worker):
    def raise_wage(self,increase):
        self.wage+=increase

#manager2=manager("John Wood",3000,"IT")

#manager2.showtheknowledges()
```

Note: `#manager2` parts can be run, I just added `#` to not use `manager2`.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "continue" in OOPS context. You should work upon your understanding of inheritance. Go through wiki on [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) or read a good CS/Python intro book.

Comment: why do you define `class manager` two times? It makes no sense. It is NOT `inheritance` but you simply replace class. But you should rather first define one class `manager` with all needed functions and later create instance `manager1`.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Worker` and `class Manager` - it helps to recognize class in code. Other good rule: put all classes at the beginning of code (after `import`). More [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT inheritance but simple replacement of class `manager`. But this is useless.

You should first define class `manager` with all needed functions and later create instance.

---

**By The Way:**

There is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Worker` and `class Manager` - it helps to recognize class in code - and `lower_case_names` for functions and variables.

Other good rule: put all classes at the beginning of code (after `import`).

Other good rule: use spaces and empty lines to make code more readable.

More [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

```
# --- imports ---

# empty

# --- classes ---

class Worker():

    def __init__(self, name, wage, department):
        self.name = name
        self.wage = wage
        self.department = department

    def show_knowledges(self):
        # longer but more readable
        print("name =", self.name)
        print("wage =", self.wage)
        print("department =", self.department)

    def change_department(self, new_department):
        self.department = new_department

class Manager(Worker):

    def raise_wage(self, increase):
        self.wage += increase

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

manager = Manager("John Wood", 3000, "IT")

manager.show_knowledges()

manager.change_department("marketing")

manager.raise_wage(1000)   # <--- use function from class `Manager`

manager.show_knowledges()
```

Result:

```
name = John Wood
wage = 3000
department = IT
name = John Wood
wage = 4000
department = marketing
```